# Proportional editing change size problem

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, object-mode, tools, proportional-editing

can anybody tell me please how can I change "proportional change size mode" on blender 3.5 to older one. I mean until I apply a proportional size that suits me(L-mouse button) it won't save. I can't save the size when I press the R-mouse button(cancel) after scrolling the mouse wheel(resizing).
In general how can I find or do anything to change proportional size without pressing the L-mouse button. As it was before. Thanks.

[image: proportional size round]

Comment: Oh, good question. I never noticed this, but maybe because I use it just once in a while and adjust it each time new for the specific part I'm editing... I can only imagine this behaviour was changed because there are so many users getting lost because they sometimes have the size so large or so small that they don't find it anymore... but I really no idea if there is a way to change that.

Comment: That's interesting in Blender 3.4.1 the size is still saved for further use.

Comment: This change is pretty annoying, would be nice to have an option to set it back to how it used to work. Having to left click to set the size sometimes changes parts of the mesh that were not intended to be changed, unless I'm missing something.